# Table Creation and data not getting save using Hibernate and JSP

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, jsp

I am new to hibernate and using it for first time.I am creating a simple form for saving the data in my database(MYSQL) using Hibernate and JSP page. But when I am clicking on register button my second page opens but with empty page. My data is not saving in DB and no table creation is happening.
Please suggest me the things I am missing
My Code is

User.java

```
  public class User {

        private int id;  
        private String name;
        private String password;
        private String email;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        //getter and setter
```

Index.jsp file

```
 <form action="register.jsp" method="post">  
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br><br/>  
Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br><br/>  
Email ID:<input type="text" name="email"/><br><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="register"/>"
```

UserDao.java Fie

```
 package com.mypack.bean;
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  
 public class UserDao {  

    public static int register(User u){  
     int i=0;  
     Session session=new Configuration().  
     configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();        
     Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  
     t.begin();  
     i=(Integer)session.save(u);  
     t.commit();  
     session.close(); 
      return i;  
    }  
     }
```

register.jsp file

```
 <%@page import="com.mypack.bean.UserDao"%>  
         <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.mypack.bean.User">  
         </jsp:useBean>  
         <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>  
         <%  
           out.println("inside");
           int i=UserDao.register(obj);  
           if(i>0)   
           out.print("You are successfully registered");  
           %>  
              // hibernate.cfg.xml file

     <hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskmanager</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource ="user.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

user.hbm.xml file

```
 <hibernate-mapping>  
        <class name="com.mypack.bean.User" table="userstable">  
        <id name="id">  
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
        </id>  
        <property name="name"></property>  
        <property name="password"></property>  
       <property name="email"></property>  
       </class>  

       </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Changes are needed,

1) Each POJO class must be need Default Constructor with Hibernate, So add
   Default Constructor into User.java file

2) Change form action value is `<form action="UserDao" method="post">`

3) Change method name into UserDao.java file `public static void 
   main(String[] arg){}`

4) Remove this line `i=(Integer)session.save(u)` and replace with 
   following code

```
`
User u = new User();
```

u.setName("abc");

u.setEmail("abc@abc.com");

session.save(u);
    `